# Any way to get list of accounts of my iPhone device programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to get all account which is added in my device

Like: go to
Settings --> Mail, Contacts, Calendars --> ACCOUNTS section

iCloud
Yahoo!
Gmail

Then I want this three name

Is there any API?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways I know of doing this.

1. If you're looking to browse files of an existing iPhone backup by iTunes or want a new iPhone backup - iExplorer lets you browse the raw files and folders that are created every time you backup your device with iTunes and it can seamlessly parse various database files such as your text messages, notes, voicemails, etc, thereby making everything easily readable and exportable.
2. You can write a shell script to parse the raw data of the backup. This will more then likely require a jail broken iPhone and openssh to mount the iPhone file system and parse it
3. You can use the code of others who have tried this: [http://code.google.com/p/linuxsleuthing/downloads/detail?name=iphone_tools_20110726.tar.gz&can=2&q=]